# Detect screen height and crop full-size image

Tags: javascript, css, image, crop

there's a very cool and subtle effect I've seen on many sites, mostly used for landing pages.
The background-image is set fullsize over the entire screen and gets cropped in height depending on the screen size (or more specifically the screen height).

This [example](http://www.designarena.de/) shows what I mean. Just resize the window to see the effect.
I don't know what this technique is called and I sure don't know how to code it. Obviously there's Javascript and some kind of overflow:hidden involved.

Any clues..?

Comment: Maybe this will help you on your way: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Looks like just CSS. Not really need for JS.

Comment: In this case the background image simply covers the entire screen and is centered horizontally, which solves one half of the problem.
In my example the image is cropped due to browser height, though. Basically the DIV containing the image must get cropped. That can only be done with JS, right...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@APAD1 is right, so this is an alternative idea for browsers not supporting `background-size`:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/TS64y/

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -200px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Please, stop using js for everything.

Comment: I'll try it out tomorrow, thank you. Nice to know, it's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

It's pure CSS, it uses background-size, not supported in IE8 and lower:

```
background: url(path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

[Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)

Comment: Thanks! :) 
IE being weird again... aargh...!